# meaning of :t in zsh

Tags: zsh

This is probably in the zsh manual, apologies for being lazy and asking it here.  There seems to be something special about :t in zsh, as witnessed by the following example.

```
% x=foo
% echo $x:bar
foo:bar
% echo $x:toad
foooad
```

The behavior with `$x:bar` is the expected one, but `:t` seems to backspace.  Can someone direct me to the appropriate section in the manual that discusses this?  Thanks!

Comment: Would man zshexpn  ( https://linux.die.net/man/1/zshexpn ) scrolling down to the ***Modifiers*** paragraph help ?

Comment: FYI, it's not specific to zsh. It's from csh in the late 70s and is also found in vim. Also in bash but only for history expansion.

Comment: @MC68020 or `info zsh modifiers`

Comment: This is the kind of thing that leads me to just always use braces and quotes. It's just easier to write `"${x}:toad"` than it is to think about whether I need to write that, even though it's a few keypresses longer than `$x:toad`. (Very occasionally it's actually important to *not* quote; I don't think it's ever necessary to omit the braces)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`:t` is a [Modifier](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers)

> `t [ digits ]`
> Remove all leading pathname components, leaving the final component (tail). This works like ‘`basename`’. Any trailing slashes
> are first removed. Decimal digits are handled as described above for
> (h), but in this case that number of trailing components is preserved
> instead of the default 1; 0 is treated the same as 1.

```
% x=/foo/bar/baz
% echo $x:toad 
bazoad
% echo $x:t
baz
% echo ${x:t2}
bar/baz
```

(`:t`, from csh was there from the start in 1990 while the `:t2` variant was [added in 2019](https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2019/msg00471.html) first available in version 5.8).

Answer (score 6):

That's a modifier – `variable:modifier` allows to modify variables when they are expanded. In your case, to make this more visible:

```bash
echo ${x:t}bar
```

removes all the leading pathname components in `x`. (try setting `x=/usr/bin/foo`!)

Honestly, I try to train myself to *never* use "raw" `$variable` in strings – the risk of complications is too high (`x=foo; xy=bar`, `echo $xyz`…); going for `echo ${x}:toad` erases any risk of your shell being any smarter than you want it here.